# extra context with django-registration

Tags: django, django-registration

Am using django-registration but I have a problem.
I want to get the login status of a user and pass it to all the html pages in my project. I normally just declare it in my views.py like this

`logged_in =request.user.is_authenticated() # get login status`

and then pass it as a context to corresponding htmls. now am using django-registration and I need to pass `logged_in` to all the htmls rendered by django-registation but am not sure how to do this. I am trying to not modify the django-registration code. I have a feeling i need context_processors but am lost as to what I really need to do here. help please !!

Comment: The request object is accessible in the html files, so {% if request.user.is_authenticated %} ... {% endif %} would work

Comment: @karthikr Yes but the problem is that request is not part of the contexts in django-registration. how do I add this extra context ? help

Comment: Well, the request_context would have the request object. It does not matter whether which app you use. In the HTML, you do not have to do anything different to access the request object. A plain {{request}} would give you access to it.

Comment: @karthikr It seems you don't get me. django registration form returns a dictionary like this `{'form':form}`, request is not passed to the template so when i try it, it does not exist in my base template. `  {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}` always gives a false value. i was thinking of adding request as an extra context or?

Comment: My guess is, you have a bigger problem than just sending a parameter here. The reason is, You are trying to register, and the 3rd party app may not have addressed the scenario for logged in users. Or, you may be getting confused between registration and authentication. Try logging in, and then {% if request.user.is_authenticated %} - You should not be sending in any additional paramters to access the request object

Comment: @YehonathanQuartey, do you have any `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in your `setting.py` file?

Answer (score 1):

By adding `django.core.context_processors.request` to your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` (which comes by default) you should have a `request` instance on the templates. You can **then** access the user (which may be an authenticated `User` or an `AnonymousUser`, never `None`) on your templates by typing:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
```

Answer (score 0):

the request object itself is accessible on the html pages

better to use that in your base.html file to access it on all pages like

```
  {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
```

Comment: Thanks but the thing is that django registration does not include the `request` as part of the context. so how do I add it as an extra context ?

Comment: @YehonathanQuartey karthikkr is right context has  request object try it first it will work

Answer (score 0):

Am using django 1.4 and apparently `request` is not a default context. Or as it is I could not access `request` by default so I added this to my `settings.py` and it worked for me

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
"django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
"django.core.context_processors.debug",
"django.core.context_processors.i18n",
"django.core.context_processors.media",
"django.core.context_processors.static",
"django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
"django.core.context_processors.request",)
```

Of course in my case I only needed `"django.core.context_processors.request"` but since I am  overriding the `default context processors`, I need to add them manually in my settings